# Using jquery, how to change div position depending on variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple slider 
I have main images and thumbnails 
I want to animate the thumbnails container to the right position, put i don't want to use integer i want to use width value from a variable

My HTML code is some thing like that

```
<div class="Slider" >
  <ul class="main-image">
    <li><img src="images/gal-1.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="images/gal-2.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="images/gal-3.jpg" alt=""/></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="thumbnails-holder">
    <a class="prev"></a>
     <div class="thumbnails-items">
      <a  class="thumbnails-item">
        <img src="images/gal-1.jpg"  alt=""/>
      </a>
       <a  class="thumbnails-item">
        <img src="images/gal-2.jpg"  alt=""/>
      </a>
       <a  class="thumbnails-item">
        <img src="images/gal-3.jpg"  alt=""/>
      </a>
     </div>
    <a class="next"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

My J query code

```
var ThumbWidth = parseInt($(".thumbnails-item").width());

                $(".next").click(function(){

                     $(this).parents().find(".thumbnails-items").animate({
                    right: '-=95'
                    })                                      
                })
```

is there a way to write it like right: '-=ThumbWidth'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ThumbWidth = parseInt($(".thumbnails-item").width());
$(".next").click(function() {
    $(this).parents().find(".thumbnails-items").animate({
        right: '-=' + ThumbWidth
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay but i tried this before and for sorry it doesn't work

Comment: @FatimahHegazy, try now and let me know if it still doesnt work

Comment: Thanks for your updates, but why i should use .each(function(){}) I have only one div.thumbnails-items holds all the thumbnails items ... for sorry adding each  doesn't make any difference

Comment: @FatimahHegazy, can you reproduce this in a fiddle? When you say doesnt make a difference do you mean it gives an error?

Comment: Thanks a lot   right: '-=' + ThumbWidth  this solution works fine.